# How to create if conditional for setOnClickListener in Android

Tags: android, if-statement, onclicklistener

I want to create If Conditional for `setOnCLickListener`, i create if conditional for variable Comment `( ImageButton )` when the `forApproval.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE` value of Comment is like

```
ImageButton Comment = (ImageButton) fidViewById(R.id.apprComment);
```

because i have a different design in one layout and different function if i create *ex 2layout it's not efficient *i think

```
final LinearLayout forApproval = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ForApproval);
final LinearLayout forRequest = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ForRequest);

ImageButton Comment = null;
ImageButton Edit = null;

if (forApproval.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
    Comment = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.apprComment);
}

// I Want to create multi value in Edit, example in here
if (forRequest.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
    Edit = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.reqEdit);
}

if (forApproval.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
    Edit = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.apprEdit);
}

// I have some ImageButton in Layout, each ImageButton has a different id
// and i want to make if conditional example like ImageButton ( in LinearLayout ) 
// is VISIBLE value of Edit is ImageButton with id reqEdit otherwise is 
// ImageButton in ( LinearLayout VISIBLE value of Edit is ImageButton with id apprEdit


Edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
           // TODO your Script
    }
});

Comment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
           // TODO your Script
    }
});
```

But i have error :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ImageButton.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
                                                                           at dca.application.taaku.hr.AttendandItemId.onCreate(AttendandItemId.java:194)
```

The Problem is in here :

```
Edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
```

Anyone can suggest me?

Comment: I didn't understand what you asked. You can have if statement inside your OnCLickListener.

Comment: i forget to add my error inside question

Comment: please explain, we cant understand your question.

Comment: Ok, i create if conditional in my code. but i had an error in Edit.setOnClickListener error in my question ( i update the question )

Comment: @JasonDoe that Edit and Comment buttons are at same place in your UI ?

Comment: try below answer by @Shweta Chauhan

Comment: ImageButton Comment = null;
ImageButton Edit = null;   remove null from both the lines simple do like this      ImageButton Comment;
ImageButton Edit;       And cast your button outside the if condition.

Comment: Yes @Nilam Vaddoriya

Comment: @Shweta Chauhan I have some ImageButton in Layout, each ImageButton has a different id and i want to make if conditional example like ImageButton ( in LinearLayout ) is VISIBLE value of Edit is ImageButton with id reqEdit otherwise is ImageButton in ( LinearLayout VISIBLE value of Edit is ImageButton with id apprEdit

Comment: that's a classic case! It is recommended to have one layout for each activity but if you have multiple choices, be very subtle with views. Use views that you set as layout and actually exist. BTW check visibility is not appropriate for checking.

Comment: it's simple.
change getvisibilty() to .Visibility

Comment: getVisiblity() method does not works what you think.
until setVisibility() method call.

Comment: If you want an answer that works for you without getting headache when you go through all potential answers, give us the code that you decide which layout to show(setContentView).

Comment: @reinhard.lee i call the method setVisibility() before this code, and it's work but i need to create a dynamic variable fro Edit because i my code is very huge on onClick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need a dynamical variable to create if conditional for OnClick. I Suggest you to try debugging forRequest.getVisibility() and forApproval.getVisibility() just before crash point, so that you can see the result and fix the present issue for If Conditional

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and solution, You alright i need to create dynamic variable for the onClick Method but i don't understand cause i'm newbie, you have suggest to create dynamic variable?

Answer (score 3):

Try this: Give If condition to clicklistener

```
Comment = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.apprComment);
Edit = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.reqEdit);

if (forRequest.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
    Edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View arg0) {
         // TODO your Script
         }
    });
}
if (forApproval.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
    Comment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onClick(View arg0) {
         // TODO your Script
         }
     });
}
```

Comment: please check my update, because i need  more values from if in Edit

Comment: ohk let me check

Comment: I have some ImageButton in Layout, each ImageButton has a different id and i want to make if conditional example like ImageButton ( in LinearLayout ) is VISIBLE value of Edit is ImageButton with id reqEdit otherwise is ImageButton in ( LinearLayout VISIBLE value of Edit is ImageButton with id apprEdit

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
       if (forRequest.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
         // perform your action here
       }
    }
});

Comment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
      if (forApproval.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
         // perform your action here
      }
    }
});
```

Comment: please check my update, because i need more values from if in Edit

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and solution, it's work but i need to create dynamic variable because my code is very huge

Answer (score 1):

the NullPointer exception is because both the forApproval and forRequest views are not visible and hence the ImageButton Edit is null. Try debugging forRequest.getVisibility() and  forApproval.getVisibility() just before the crash point so that you can fix the present issue. But if this bit of code is in the onCreate() then you are going to face further issues, it will be better to name reqEdit and apprEdit differently.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation

Answer (score 0):

Your are initialising Comment only when  forApproval is visible due to that it is null in other case and same for Edit also if both are not visible

try this

```
final LinearLayout forApproval = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ForApproval);
final LinearLayout forRequest = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.ForRequest);

ImageButton Comment ;
ImageButton Edit = null;

if (forRequest.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
    Edit = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.reqEdit);
}
if (forApproval.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
    Comment = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.apprComment);
    Edit = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.apprEdit);
}
 if(Comment!=null){

   Comment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
           // TODO your Script
    }
});}
if(Edit!=null){
    Edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
           // TODO your Script
    }
});}
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and solution, it's work but i need to create dynamic variable because my code is very huge

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 solutions,

**`SOLUTION 1`**

```
int REQUEST=1,APPROVAL=2, FORWHAT=0;

if (forRequest.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
    Edit = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.reqEdit);
    FORWHAT=REQUEST;
}

if (forApproval.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
    Edit = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.apprEdit);
    FORWHAT=APPROVAL;
}

Edit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
           // TODO your Script
      if(FORWHAT==REQUEST){
            //TODO request code
      }else if(FORWHAT==APPROVAL){
            //TODO approval code
      }else{
           //TODO something else
      }
    }
});
```

**`SOLUTION 2`**

```
ImageButton comment; //variable starts with small letters.
ImageButton editRequest,editApproval;

 comment = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.apprComment);
 editRequest = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.reqEdit);
 editApproval = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.apprEdit);

comment.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
           // TODO your Script
    }
});
editRequest.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
           // TODO your Script
    }
});
editApproval.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
           // TODO your Script
    }
});
if (forApproval.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
    comment.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}

// I Want to create multi value in Edit, example in here
if (forRequest.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
    editRequest.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    editApproval.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

if (forApproval.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
    editApproval.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    editRequest.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and solution, it's work but i need to create dynamic variable because my code is very huge

Comment: then you can use my solution 1 , store many values in array and check it after click listener and perform task