# Trying to change Activity with an If that gets the value of a TxtView, but it´s not working

Tags: java, android

I´m trying to change the Activity with a button, that checks the value of a TxtView, if the value is 1, it should change the activity, but it doesn't.
I already checked that the TxtOut is returning "1" as the value, and it does.

```
check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (txtOut == "1"){
                    Intent c = new Intent(qr_activity.this,cuestionarioCotizador01.class);
                    startActivity(c);
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(qr_activity.this, "No", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: use `.equals()` instead of `==` , for example: `if(txtOut.equals("1"))`

Comment: Just tried it, but it also didn´t work :(

Answer (score 0):

it's better to check your condition first, this may help:

```
if(txtOut.equals("1")) {
    check.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent c = new Intent(qr_activity.this,cuestionarioCotizador01.class);
                startActivity(c);
        }
    });
} else {
    ...}
```

Comment: Found something interesting, if I give the TextView the text "1" on the xml, it works, but if i delete it, and try to get it from by obtaining the text from a QR code, it doesn´t work.

Comment: I'm still working on it

Comment: @DiegoAlv. found a similar issue maybe the answers help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46188839/how-to-create-if-conditional-for-setonclicklistener-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will solve your problem.

```
checkB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (checkTV.getText().toString().equals("1")){
                    Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Experiment2.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else {
                    Toast.makeText(Experiment.this, "It is not 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.d("TAG","It is not 1");
                }
            }
        });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).